# how to use switchMap to cancel pending http requests and taking the last subscribe only?

Tags: angular, rxjs, httprequest, observable, switchmap

i tried canceling pending  http request using subscription.unsubsribe like this:

```
getAgentList(pageNumber: number, filter: string): any {
   let requestUrl: string = 'api/service/agents_search?ACCT=' 
   +this.accountId;

if ( this.subscription ) {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

this.subscription =  this.backEndCommService.getData(requestUrl)
.subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
        let serverResponse: ServerResponse = new 
        ServerResponse(this.accountId, pageNumber, res.search_results, 
        res.resultRows, res.pageSize, res.resultPages)
                this._agentListData.next(serverResponse);
            },   
       (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                let errorMessage: string;
                if (err instanceof TypeError) {
                    errorMessage = 'Script error: ' + err.message;
                } 
                console.log(errorMessage);
    });
}
```

I wonder how can I apply switchMap to this code in order to kill pending requests to the URL ( for example autocompletion search input when first search taking to much time and a second one entered and I want to dismiss the first one.)
thanks

Answer (score 9):

basic example:

```
export class MyComponent{
    private $filter: Subject<string> = new Subject<String>();

    constructor(){
        this.$filter
          .switchMap(filter => this.backEndCommService.getData(filter + this.baseUrl)
          .subscribe(res => {//do something})
    }

    getAgentList(filterValue: string){
        this.$filter.next(filterValue);
    }

}
```

To use switchmap to cancel previous request we need a hot observable which outputs our filter value. We use a subject for that. Everytime we get a new value from somewhere? we push it to the subject.

Comment: thanks for your answer it sound promissing but when i tried it the call to the server did not even got out and it fall silently with no errors what so ever... pls see code:

Comment: 1. Did you subscribe? 2. Did you call `next` AFTER you subscribe?

Comment: This explanation helped me fix a http cancelling problem. I hadn't realized that switchMap unsubscribes the previous one.

Comment: do you still ne ngOnDestroy or not?

Comment: Yes, you almost always need to unsubscribe from a hot observable.

Comment: With this pattern, the switchMap seems to die if any of the calls to the web service fails.

Comment: I would recommend unsubscribe on OnDestroy life hook

Answer (score 0):

tried  and it even did not got out to the server

```
getAgentList(pageNumber: number, filter: string): any {
    let requestUrl: string = 'api/service/agents_search?ACCT=' 
  +this.accountId;
    if (filter) {
        requestUrl = requestUrl + '&filter=' + filter;
    }
    if (pageNumber) {
        requestUrl = requestUrl + '&pageNumber=' + pageNumber;
    }
    this.$filter.next(requestUrl)

    this.$filter.switchMap(requestUrl => 
    this.backEndCommService.getData(requestUrl))
            .subscribe(
                (res: any) => {
                    let serverResponse: ServerResponse = new 
                    ServerResponse(this.accountId, pageNumber, 
                    res.search_results, 
                    res.resultRows, res.pageSize, res.resultPages)
                    this._agentListData$.next(serverResponse);
                },
               (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {

            console.log('handling error');
      });
}
```

this line switchMap(requestUrl => 
    this.backEndCommService.getData(requestUrl)) did not made the call and 
  fall silently.....mmmm

Comment: This doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You should ignore the meanning of variable names. Lets ignore the code...
I want to code a getdata funxtion that will create url and will hit the server and if its pending and i get new request the pending will be canceled. How do i achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that the `subscription` is done after the `next`. Think of it like `addEventListener` on the DOM. You receive events after you add the listener, or in this case, the subscriber.

```
getAgentList(pageNumber: number, filter: string): any {
    let requestUrl: string = ‘...’

    // assuming this.$filter is a Subject
    // subscription to it first
    this.$filter.switchMap(requestUrl => this.backEndCommService.getData(requestUrl))
        .subscribe(
            (res: any) => {
                let serverResponse: ServerResponse = new 
                ServerResponse(this.accountId, pageNumber, 
                res.search_results, 
                res.resultRows, res.pageSize, res.resultPages)
                this._agentListData$.next(serverResponse);
            },
           (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                console.log('handling error')
           }
    );

    // then call next()
    this.$filter.next(requestUrl)
}
```

That’s probably it. Unless, `this.$filter` is a BehaviorSubject or ReplaySubject, then we may have a different problem.

Comment: Just noticed this was pointed out by @robindijkhof but maybe seeing it in full will make it more obvious