# cancel current requests by service and only get the results of the last request

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that gets triggered to make calls on the backend How can I cancel previous ongoing requests to only get the last request result back
my code is :

```
 this.vehiclesService.getVehiclesByPage(currentState).subscribe(success => {
        this.cache[backendPage] = true;
        this.setPageResult({ ...success, page: backendPage, pageSize: pageInfo.pageSize * 10 });
      });
```

I tried to add a debounceTime like this but it didn't seem to work

```
 this.vehiclesService.getVehiclesByPage(currentState).pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(success => {
        this.cache[backendPage] = true;
        this.setPageResult({ ...success, page: backendPage, pageSize: pageInfo.pageSize * 10 });
      });
```

I believe that a switchMap should do the trick yet I don't know how to combine it with my code
Can anyone show me how to add it ?

Comment: Once a request is sent it cannot be canceled. You can however, just ignore the response...

Comment: how can I only get the response of the last request that got sent?

Comment: Use `takeLast(1)` to get a last emission from a response.

Comment: I would ask about the scenario of how you're sending many requests, it depends on sin the currentState value? I would suggest using switchMap operator

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Http requests can be aborted, for example with [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController/abort)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use switchMap to cancel pending http requests and taking the last subscribe only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49152025/how-to-use-switchmap-to-cancel-pending-http-requests-and-taking-the-last-subscri)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're creating a new observable each time you make the http request. The simplest option is to use a shared `Subject` that you can push values to.

```js
// create single, shared Subject
let webRequestTriggers = new Subject();

// subscribe to the Subject once at the beginning
function initialise() {
  webRequestTriggers.pipe(
    switchMap(currentState => this.vehiclesService.getVehiclesByPage(currentState))
  )
  .subscribe(success => {
    this.cache[backendPage] = true;
    this.setPageResult({ ...success, page: backendPage, pageSize: pageInfo.pageSize * 10 });
  });
}

// probably in some kind of event handler or function that you have defined somewhere, which is called whenever a page of results is requested
function fetchPagedResults(currentState) {
  webRequestTriggers.next(currentState);
}
```

Comment: If this is in a method, each time the method is called you'll probably again create a new subject . So it might be better to move the Subject to a field level. The key solution is `switchMap` tho so yeah the rest is clean up I guess :-)